# Word Document has two footers after importing from LibreOffice

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice

I am having a weird issue with word. It seems I have two footers in the document on a single page. I am using Word for mac, the document has been imported from LibreOffice.

The issue persists in Word for Windows and Word for Mac. Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Next time LaTeX :(

[image: two word footers]

Comment: This looks like a bug cause by LibreOffice not Office.  It would be interesting to know if its a `.docx` or `.doc` file.

Answer (score 1):

It was our logic mistake. We didn't really understand the difference between footnotes and footer. On top are the footnotes, below is the footer.